# Determine the smallest positive integer m

Tags: number-theory, inequality

> The $ f $ and $ g $ functions are defined by $ f (x) = 3 ^ x $ and
>   $ g (x) = 100 ^ x $. Two strings $ a_1, a_2, a_3, ..... $ and
>   $ b_1, b_2, b_3, .... $ are defined as follows:
>
> (i) $ a_1 = 3 $ and $ a_ {n + 1} = f (a_n) $ for $ n \geq 1 $;
>
> (ii) $ b_1 = $ 100 and $ b_ {n + 1} = g (b_n) $ for $ n \geq $ 1.
>
> Determine the smallest positive integer $ m $ for which $ b_m> a_ {100}$

I believe this may come out of recurrence, but I don't know how to do it

**What did I do:**

Suppose $ b_1> a_1 $

$ b_1a_1 $ and $ b_1> a_1 ^ {a_1}, $ hence $ b_1> a_2 $

However, $ b_1 <a_1 ^ {a_1 ^ {a_1}} $, ie $ b_1 <a_3 $

Comment: This question has appeared before, recently. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425166/determine-the-smallest-positive-integer-m).  What is it's source?

Comment: @lulu I got it from a fisic list of exercises, supposedly from '' Australia ''